# Do these two DC filter algorithms achieve the same thing, and is one better?

Tags: algorithm, audio, filter, signal-processing, dc

I have two different DC filter algorithms and I'm wondering what their main differences are and if one is better than the other.

Here's a DC filter algorithm from [dsprelated.com](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/DC_Blocker.html):

```
y = x - xm1 + 0.995 * ym1;
xm1 = x;
ym1 = y;
```

And here's the one I'm currently using, which is actually a low-pass filter that's inverted to make a high pass:

```
y += (x - y) * 0.005;
output = x - y;
```

For clarity, `x` is the current input sample in both cases. In the first example, `y` would be the output and, in the second example, `output` would be the output.

In the first example, there are 2 states (`xm1` and `ym1`), and in mine there's only one (`y`). Doing some number crunching shows that the latter algorithm has a slower response than the first, but they do both function as low-frequency high-pass filters.

I understand that this might be subjective, but is there a preference for one of these algorithms over the other and, if so, why?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the output of each filter y<sub>t</sub> in terms of x<sub>t</sub>, x<sub>t-1</sub>, and y<sub>t-1</sub>

Filter 1:

y<sub>t</sub> = x<sub>t</sub> - x<sub>t-1</sub> + 0.995y<sub>t-1</sub>

Filter 2:

Note that `y = x-output` in the original formulation, so:

y<sub>t</sub> = x<sub>t</sub> - ( x<sub>t-1</sub> - y<sub>t-1</sub> + 0.005 ( x<sub>t</sub> - x<sub>t-1</sub> + y<sub>t-1</sub>) )

y<sub>t</sub> = x<sub>t</sub> -  x<sub>t-1</sub> + y<sub>t-1</sub> - 0.005 ( x<sub>t</sub> - x<sub>t-1</sub> + y<sub>t-1</sub>) )

y<sub>t</sub> = x<sub>t</sub> -  x<sub>t-1</sub> + y<sub>t-1</sub> - 0.005 ( x<sub>t</sub> - x<sub>t-1</sub> + y<sub>t-1</sub>) )

y<sub>t</sub> = 0.995x<sub>t</sub> - 0.995x<sub>t-1</sub> + 0.995y<sub>t-1</sub>

This is exactly the same as the first filter, except a little quieter.  Multiplying the original signal by 1/0.995, we get exactly the same result.

If you use `output = (x-y)*(1.0/0.995)`, then you get the same filter.

I don't see much reason to prefer one formulation over the other.